# Properly dereferencing pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I am struggling handling my pointers in a piece of C++ code. Without further ado, let me show you a portion of my code:

In `file1.cpp`

```
void *SomeClass::extract()
{
    double foo = 3.14;
    return (void*) &foo; // returns the pointer to a double
}
```

In `file2.cpp`

```
void * bar = SomeClass->extract(); // fetches the pointer to a double
fprintf(screen, "pointer address: %p \t value: %.3e \n", bar, (double*) bar);
```

(Because of the massive oversimplification of the code, there may be inconsistencies.) What I basically want to do is print out the value of `foo` in `file2.cpp`, which is retrieved by calling a function in `file1.cpp`. When I compare the pointer addresses of `foo` and `bar`, I find that they are identical. But when I want to dereference the pointer, I get bogus. I suspect I'm doing something wrong in the dereferencing, but when I compare this to other sections of the code (which I did not write myself by the way), it seems valid.

I am aware that this is supposed be very basic C++, but somehow it is not working for me. I'd be very grateful if someone could explain me how this is done properly.

Martijn

Comment: `(double *)` bar only casts bar to a pointer of type `double*`.  You still need to dereference the pointer

Comment: You are returning a pointer into the stack. Next function will overwrite it with whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to return a pointer to an automatic variable, which will be destroyed as soon as the `extract` function exits. You then try and dereference a pointer to an invalid object, which is undefined behaviour.

If you want to return a pointer from a function, you need to allocate memory for it on the free store, then return the pointer and remember to delete it later:

```
double *SomeClass::extract()
{
    double *foo = new double(3.14);
    return foo;
}
```

Then to get at the value of this pointer, you need to dereference it:

```
double * bar = SomeClass->extract(); // fetches the pointer to a double
fprintf(screen, "pointer address: %p \t value: %.3e \n", bar, *bar);
```

Or if you insist on using `void*` for some reason, make sure you dereference the result of the pointer cast:

```
void * bar = SomeClass->extract(); // fetches the pointer to a double
fprintf(screen, "pointer address: %p \t value: %.3e \n", bar, *(double*) bar);
//                                                       here ^
```

However, builtin types like `double` are designed to be passed around by value, so you should not generally allocate them dynamically.

```
double SomeClass::extract()
{
    return 3.14;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Some of your remarks do not apply to my code, although it may appear so in my oversimplified example. However, your `*(double*)` did the trick for me.

Comment: @MPA What doesn't apply? This all sounds like solid advice no matter what you're doing. Arnd are you absolutely sure you need to return a pointer, especially a void*? Maybe you can post more about your use case

Comment: @evan The `extract()` function should be able to return both `int`, `double` and `double**`, thus it seem like I have to resort to returning a `void*` pointer. If you know of any alternative methods, please let me know.

Comment: Is `extract` is some virtual function which you are overriding in different derived classes which represent different types?

Comment: There are lots of solutions depending in your needs: function templates, overloaded functions, returning boost::any, probably several others. There are different difficulty levels involved but keep your code type safe if possible. Also return by value. I don't see what using a pointer type gives you.